# Plot different columns of different DataFrame in the same plot with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have two differents Data Frames:

```
DF1: with columns A B1 C1 D1 E1
DF2: with columns A B2 C2 D2 E2
```

With A being the same for the two of them.

then I want to plot two plots in the same figure, one at the right and the other at the left with this information:

```
Plot 1: x axis = column A
        y axis = B1, B2, C1, C2 curves

Plot 2: x axis = column A
        y axis = D1, D2, E1, E2 curves
```

How can I do it without merge the two DF using Pandas and Matplotlib?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The idea would be to create an axes `ax` and a twin axes `ax2 = ax.twinx()` and to then plot each dataframe to one of them, `df.plot(ax=ax)` and `df2.plot(ax=ax2)`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.linspace(-5,5, 11)
data1 = np.sort(np.random.rand(len(a),5))
data1[:,0] =a 
data2 = np.sort(np.random.rand(len(a),5))*10
data2[:,0] =a 
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=["A", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=["A", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

df.plot(x="A", y=["B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"], ax=ax)
df2.plot(x="A", y=["B2", "C2", "D2", "E2"], ax=ax2, ls="--")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead you want to have two separate plots (the question is not clear on this point), you can do it by

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
```

and removing the `twinx` call.

[image]

Comment: Mindblown that no one else has upvoted this, yet.  Great explanation and solid figures.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
```

which will create a plot containing 1 row and 2 columns of subplots. 
It will probably be the easiest way to obtain the columns of the data frames using

```
A = DF1['A']
...
```

in case matplotlib does not like to be fed directly with the data frame columns.

You can then plot the columns into the different subplots. This looks like the following example:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.plot(A, B1, label='...')
ax1.plot(A, B2, label='...')
...
ax2.plot(A, D1, label='...')
ax2.plot(A, D2, label='...')
...
ax1.legend(loc='best')
ax2.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```