# Plots different columns of different dataframe in one plot as scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I am trying to plot different columns (longitude & latitude ) from different dataframes in one plot. But they are being plotted in different figures separately.

Here is the code I am using

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()

cells_final.plot.scatter(x='lon',y='lat')
data_rupture.plot.scatter(x='Longitude',y='Latitude',color='red')
plt.show()
```

How can I plot this in one single figure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot different columns of different DataFrame in the same plot with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574099/plot-different-columns-of-different-dataframe-in-the-same-plot-with-pandas)

Comment: I tried that, But it still appears in two different figures , Don't know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `axes` instance (`ax`) created by

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

And pass it as the `ax` parameter of [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html),

```py
fig,ax=plt.subplots()

cells_final.plot.scatter(x='lon',y='lat', ax=ax)
data_rupture.plot.scatter(x='Longitude',y='Latitude',color='red', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Or if you'd rather have the plots on different [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) in the same figure you can create multiple axes

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

cells_final.plot.scatter(x='lon',y='lat', ax=ax1)
data_rupture.plot.scatter(x='Longitude',y='Latitude',color='red', ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need specify the axis:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12, 8))

cells_final.plot.scatter(x='lon',y='lat', ax=ax=[0])
data_rupture.plot.scatter(x='Longitude',y='Latitude',color='red', ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Actually I want both scatter plot with different colour from different data frames in one Plot rather than two different subplots

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output]

Thanks @William Miller.......!