# Combine two plots from two different .csv files and add a secondary y axis inpython

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am attempting to create a single plot with variables from two different .csv files. My current code creates two separate plots for all the .csvs in a folder. However I want these two plots to be plotted together with C on the primary y axis and rew_binary on the secondary Y axis. Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
files = Path('./mA1_2022_03_23_csplit').glob('*.csv')
recode = pd.read_csv('./mA1_2022_03_23_recode.csv', index_col = 0)
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col = 0)
    df.plot(x = 'time_ms', y = 'C', title = file)
    recode.plot(kind = 'bar', x = 'time_ms', y = 'rew_binary')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot different columns of different DataFrame in the same plot with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574099/plot-different-columns-of-different-dataframe-in-the-same-plot-with-pandas)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.